# Laravel Cashier calls stripe setup_intents twice and getting setup_intent_unexpected_state error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel Cashier and trying to get a simple subscription selection and payment method setup form created. I've followed all the examples and everything, but i keep getting an `setup_intent_unexpected_state` error which kills the whole process.

For some reason it is calling `/v1/setup_intents/seti_1LZ4THKAmQBe3qdGJ1QMWXZ7/confirm` twice.

Here is my blade view file code:

```
<form
    id="subscribe-form"
    class="o-form o-form--login js-form"
    method="POST"
    action="{{ route('app.user.subscription') }}"
    data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}"
    data-submit-log-event="subscribed"
>
    @csrf
    <input class="sr-only" type="hidden" name="selected_subscription_product" value="{{ $plans->first()->product->id }}" />
    <div class="o-form__fields-plans">
        @foreach ($plans as $plan)
            <div class="o-form__field o-form__field--radio">
                <h3 class="o-form__field-label" id="tier-standard">{{ $plan->product->name }}</h3>
                <input class="o-form__field-radio" id="subscription-{{ $plan->id }}" class="sr-only" type="radio" name="selected_subscription_price" value="{{ $plan->id }}" />
                <label class="o-form__field-label">
                    ${{ number_format($plan->amount/100, 2) }}
                    <span class="o-form__field-label-sub"> /{{ $plan->interval }} </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="o-dash-info-card__content">
        <div class="o-form__field o-form__field--payment">
            <label class="o-form__field-label">{{ __('Payment') }}</label>
            <div id="card-element" class="o-form__field-input"></div>
            <input id="payment-method" type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to_new" value="{{ $redirectToNew ? 'true' : 'false' }}" />

    @include('objects.button', [
        'button' => [
            'title' => __('Subscribe'),
            'appearance' => 'solid',
            'color' => 'base-900',
        ],
        'classes' => 'o-dash-info-card__cta',
        'id' => 'submit-button'
    ])
</form>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    const stripe = Stripe('{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}');
    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const cardElement = elements.create('card');

    cardElement.mount('#card-element');

    const cardHolderName = '{{ Auth::user()->getFullName() }}';
    const paymentMethod = document.getElementById('payment-method');
    const cardButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
    const registerForm = document.getElementById('subscribe-form');
    const clientSecret = registerForm.dataset.secret;

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
            clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: cardElement,
                    billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                }
            }
        );

        if (error) {
            // @TODO: implement proper error messaging
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
            paymentMethod.value = setupIntent.payment_method;

            registerForm.requestSubmit(cardButton);
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is my controller file:

```
$data = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'selected_subscription_product' => ['required_with:selected_subscription_price', 'string'],
    'selected_subscription_price' => ['required_with:selected_subscription_product', 'string'],
    'payment_method' => ['nullable', 'string'],
    'redirect_to_new' => ['nullable', 'string'],
])->validate();

$user = Auth::user();

$user->newSubscription($data['selected_subscription_product'], $data['selected_subscription_price'])
    ->trialDays(config('services.stripe.trialLength'))
    ->create($data['payment_method']);

$user->track('subscribed', [
    'trial_days' => 7,
    'stripe_product_id' => $data['selected_subscription_product'],
    'stripe_price_id' => $data['selected_subscription_price']
]);

// push updated subscription details
$user->identify();

if (isset($data['redirect_to_new']) && $data['redirect_to_new'] != 'false') {
    return redirect('/new');
}

return redirect()->route('profile.show');
```

The error i'm getting:

```
{
    "error": {
      "code": "setup_intent_unexpected_state",
      "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/setup-intent-unexpected-state",
      "message": "You cannot update this SetupIntent because it has already succeeded.",
      "setup_intent": {
        "id": "################################",
        "object": "setup_intent",
        "cancellation_reason": null,
        "client_secret": ""################################",
        "created": 1661051107,
        "description": null,
        "last_setup_error": null,
        "livemode": false,
        "next_action": null,
        "payment_method": ""################################",
        "payment_method_types": [
          "card"
        ],
        "status": "succeeded",
        "usage": "off_session"
      },
      "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

So, turns out the issue was from another dev that changed a line that was `registerForm.submit();` to `registerForm.requestSubmit(cardButton);`.

This was causing the form to submit as if the submit button was clicked, instead of submitting on the form object itself.

So swapping that line back fixed it.